# member ../lib/lk/liblk.a(debugfs.o) in archive is not an object, error while cross compiling perf

Tags: linux, android, arm, cross-compilation, perf

i get the following error when i try to cross compile perf tool for arm

```
../lib/lk/liblk.a: member ../lib/lk/liblk.a(debugfs.o) in archive is not an object
```

what i have done ?

```
cd stable-kernel/tools/perf
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnu-eabi-gcc
```

surprisingly when i actually see there its a member

```
ar -t ../lib/lk/liblk.a 
debugfs.o
```

what may be the reason for this abnormal behaviour?

PS: this did not happen when i did compile for x86 (the usual way make and then make  install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because liblk.a is build for x86 and the makescript searches for a liblk.a built for ARM / required platform, so even though the liblk.a is having a member when i look at type of file , by command file liblk.a it showed me clearly that the file is built for x86 so the error raised !

so to overcome this i have first built the liblk.a for ARM and then i have run the makescript which solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to export CC to your ARM tool-chain to compile liblk.a into ARM elf format.

```
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```